# Microsoft Visual Basic Run-time error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using MS Access 2007 and VBA. I have a block of code which triggers when the quantity is greater than stock or the stock is zero.

```vb
Private Sub Quantity_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Quantity > Me.Stock Or Me.Stock = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough stocks left."
        Me.Quantity = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

The message box appears but after that an error message followed:

`Run-time error '2147352567 (80020009)':`

`The macro or function set to BeforeUpdate or ValidationRule property for this field is preventing  Microsoft Office Access from saving the data in the field.`

How to stop this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control's *Before Update* event does not allow you to change it to just any value.  You have 2 options at that point:

1. call `Cancel` and then call `Undo` to revert its value to whatever was there before the attempted update
2. call `Cancel` only, leaving the new (unacceptable) value in place, but forcing the user to replace it with an acceptable value before continuing

Here is tested sample code for the first option.  If you prefer the second option, discard the `Me.Quantity.Undo` line.

```vb
Private Sub Quantity_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.Quantity > Me.Stock Or Me.Stock = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough stocks left."
        'Me.Quantity = "" ' <-- NOT ALLOWED
        Cancel = True
        Me.Quantity.Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

When `Me.Quantity` and `Me.Stock` are text values which contain numbers, the situation is more complicated.  If it were me, I would prefer to change their data types to numeric.  But if that change is impractical, you can use `Val()` to transform the text values to actual numbers for your comparison.

```vb
Private Sub Quantity_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Val(Me.Quantity) > Val(Me.Stock) Or Val(Me.Stock) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough stocks left."
        'Me.Quantity = "" ' <-- NOT ALLOWED
        Cancel = True
        Me.Quantity.Undo
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, I so infrequently see the opportunity to use Undo or Cancel that I never think to use in an answer.

Comment: thanks. but another problem occur. when i input greater than 1 in the quantity field it displays the message box "not enough stocks left". Example the stock of this product is 100, when i input 2 or above it executes the msgbox. any ideas?

Comment: Does Access understand both `Me.Quantity` and `Me.Stock` are numeric data type instead of text?

Comment: the datatype of fields quantity and stock are in text, should i change the datatype?

Comment: If Me.Quantity is a field and not a control, wouldn't the value still be what it was the last time since this is in a before update event.  So to do this shouldn't it be something more like Me.txtQuantity (referring to a control) or am I just crazy?

Comment: Though I feel that while there isn't any explicit declaration of variables access would interperate the code to be numbers on its own.  It feels like it is referring to the Table's un-updated field, whereas it should be referring to the Forms control while performing the check.

Comment: @Newd Re: *"If Me.Quantity is a field and not a control"* ... `Quantity_BeforeUpdate` means `Quantity` must be a control, right?  I suppose it could *also* be a field, but don't see why that would change anything here.

Comment: @francisjessie Numeric data type is generally better for handling numbers. However, if changing the data type is impractical, you can transform the text to number for your comparison: `If Val(Me.Quantity) > Val(Me.Stock) Or Val(Me.Stock) = 0 Then`

Comment: So the `Val` transforms the text to number? And yes changing the data type is very impractical. Thanks for your help I learned something from you.

Comment: Yes, `Val()` returns a number from a string.  See the Access help topic for details.  Beware `Val()` will not accept a Null input.  The `Nz()` function could be useful in that case.

Comment: Ya I see your point.  After doing a quick test it looks like even if the control and the field were named the same the control is what gets interpreted.  Had the control been something like txtQuantity then my comment would have been plausible.  Though clearly barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access you can't set control values in the "BeforeUpdate" event.  So this line:

```vb
Me.Quantity = ""
```

Is causing your error message. So you will need to look for an alternative way to do what you are attempting to do.  I think that the "AfterUpdate" event will work for what you are looking for.